# Why is question 16375 considered as an attempt to a polemic question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

What makes [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/why-did-allah-encourage-people-to-come-to-the-prophet-pbuh-so-that-he-would-pl) to be considered as an attempt to a polemic question?

This question is based on Quran 's verse,and user wants its tafseer.

So,what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 3):

Ok,I assume that the part which you mentioned,leading toward a particular answer.But I can't understand what is the problem with it?!

All users have authority of accepting or denying.they can be agree with him or be disagree,so they can answer this question based on their opinion and their evidences.every body who isn't agree with this conclusion,can explain his/her opinion with evidence in his/her answer and by this answer he/she can guide the questioner,too.it is the same for a person who is agree with it.

Furthermore,the Questioner actually comes across a verse and then some questions springs to mind,His research leads him to intercession issue,but after that,he asks the question to make sure if he is right. He puts forward the question in order to avoid drawing conclusions which are against Islamic teachings..He didn't answer the question,But ask a question about this issue...

On the other hand,How can we judge about his intention?!

Also,as I see,there isn't any argument about this question,How could you call it a polemic question?!you solved a problem which isn't exist?!

However,I edited the question based on your answer;And in my mind it is really a good question and I support it.

So,considering all this;what is the problem,now?why should it be on hold?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, it's the leading question at the end:

> **Can we at least draw the conclusion that intercession is not against Islamic teachings?**

The questioner is obviously leading toward a *particular* answer.  In bold, no less.  This is a hallmark of polemic and apologetic writing; to take a verse or reference, draw a particular conclusion from it, and then frame it in such a way that it appears that only *that* particular conclusion is a reasonable interpretation.

**[THAT IS NOT WHAT THIS SITE IS FOR](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/islam-stack-exchange-is-not-for-debates-or-apologetics)**.

The question as phrased does not appear to be a practical answerable question based on an actual problem that the author faces.  It just looks like an attempt to get other users to agree with him.

Questions of that sort are not and have never been an appropriate use of this site, and fly against the philosophy of the Stack Exchange model.  We as a site are designed to allow *expert users* to get *expert answers* to their *expert question*, *not* for argument, debate, or polemic.