# Why was the question 16458 closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16458/are-muawiah-and-ayeshah-are-the-ones-with-whom-the-prophetpbuh-is-in-war) closed? It was a clear question asking whether there might be a reconciliation between the Hadith and a historical fact.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason it was closed the <strike>[first](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16433/22)</strike> [second](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16434/22) time you posted it:

> We are not a site for polemic and debate. Please focus this question to make it clear what exactly your practical answerable question is and what you're expecting in an answer.

Your first attempt at posting that question was originally closed as a duplicate of [an already answered question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2397/22) which covered exactly what you had asked,, after which you merely changed the wording to the current form with no attempt or explanation as to why the extant answer is insufficient.

And the current form uses exactly the same kind of polemic/apologetic wordplay that, as [I've already explained](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1268/22), [is *not* welcome on this site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22).

That post was closed and subsequently deleted, as was your second attempt to post the same thing.  Your <strike>[third](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16455/22)</strike> [fourth](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16458/22) attempt at posting the question again put in absolutely zero effort to actually focus the question, to make it clear, or to demonstrate that it's *not* polemic, beyond adding a comment stating that "This is a clear question…" (such comments, in my experience, never actually make anything clearer).  So it was, again, closed and deleted.

Comment: You have accused me of posting polemic question so you are the ones who have to demonstrate that it is polemic!!

Comment: @Amin No, the onus is on you to write a clear and acceptable question.  I have told you this before.