# why the question 16557 has been deleted without any reaon?

Tags: discussion

My question has beثn deleted and locked without mentioning any reason. what is the reason  of deleting? what is the relation between a verse and two important figures in early Islam.

Comment: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/islam-stack-exchange-is-not-for-debates-or-apologetics

Answer (score 1):

Please read

> [Islam—Stack Exchange is not for debates or apologetics](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/)

to understand what this site is about and why your post does not fit here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your question because I don't have reputation to see a deleted question but questions can be deleted by the community for many reasons, which is explained in the help centre.

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators. Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked.

If this doesn't explain why your question was deleted you should ask your question to make it clear what you don't actually understand, because your description is too vague for anyone to actually explain what's wrong with your post if they can't see it.