# Why is my answer been deleted without prior warning or discussion?

Tags: discussion

I made an answer in the islam stack exchange
[Is porn (pornography) allowed in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21524/is-pornography-allowed-in-islam/21530?noredirect=1#comment37537_21530)

[Is it allowed for an Islamic state to demand ransom from non-Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21538/is-it-allowed-for-an-islamic-state-to-demand-ransom-from-non-muslims/21567?noredirect=1#comment37536_21567)

and the moderator just deleted it out of the blue with a vague reason.
I wonder what is the standard for deleting an answer in the site?
Why can't he tolerate an answer that is not from his school of thought?

Because of this I just lost considerable amount of reputation points :(

Comment: Since I left comments on *both* deleted answers explaining *why* I deleted them, perhaps you could explain what part of those explanations you considered too "vague" to understand, and especially what part led you to believe it was due to my inability to "tolerate an answer that is not from [my] school of thought," considering I said nothing of the sort.

Comment: Also, the general guidelines for why answers get deleted can be found in the help centre: http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: @goldPseudo Those "not answering the question" comment is not giving a clear reason as to why that instance of answer is unrelated to the question.
Beside even if the answer is not clear, you don't just delete it. You ask the answerer to clarify his answer, if you really seek to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Please read: **[How do I write a good answer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)**

> #### Answer the question
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? **Make sure your answer provides that** – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

(emphasis mine)

Your thoughts on Arabic translation or teachings regarding restitution from aggressors *may* be relevant to the questions you were answering, but *you must tie it back to the questions as they were asked*. It's not enough to point in the general direction of an answer & leave the rest as an exercise for the reader; if there's an answer to be had, **then provide it!** Demonstrating how you arrived there is good, great in fact, but telling stories from the journey without ever arriving at a conclusion that solves the problem faced by the asker isn't.

And that's why your answers were removed. Because they didn't answer the questions they were posted in response to.

Comment: Just because i said it's up to the readers to conclude doesn't mean that i have not provided clear conclusion.
I did tie my answers to the question, i just don't get how the moderator did not get it and just deleted it out of the blue..

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see how your posts did anything to actually answer the questions, so they were deleted for not answering the questions.  [From the help centre](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers):

> Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

Both of the deleted answers were more [propaganda](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1426/22) than anything else; as written it looks like you were more interested in challenging the common understanding of a number of Arabic terms (with absolutely no authoritative references to back you up, rendering your posts indistinguishable from [mere opinion](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/22)) and attacking Islamic scholars as a group than you were in actually *answering the questions*.

And considering you have a history of…

- … arguing with constructive criticism rather than actually heeding it,
- … hostility towards users who criticise and/or curate your posts,
- … using posts as a medium to [proselytise and to challenge common beliefs](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22) rather than contribute constructively,
- … generally low-quality and unwelcome contributions to the site as a whole,

I saw no reason to believe that you'd be any more likely to heed a warning or engage in constructive discussion now than you've shown before; you have so far shown little regard for what the community actually wants or for what this site is actually geared toward.

And given that in the time since your post has been deleted, you've…

- … shown no attempt to understand the feedback that's already been provided to you,
- … presented no arguments as to how your posts actually *did* answer the questions,
- … made no attempt to [improve your posts](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1160/22) so that they clearly *did* answer the actual questions,
- … hurled [baseless accusations](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) against the moderator who curated your post,

then I see no reason to rethink my decision on this matter.  If you feel that your posts provide value to this site and should be undeleted, feel free to make a new meta post and put forth a proper argument; the entire basis of this post just seems to be that people  shouldn't delete your posts ever, which does absolutely nothing to sway me.

Comment: i dont know which argument you consider mere opinion
i have backed my arguments with quranic verses

Answer (score 0):

Questions can be deleted without prior warning if stack Exchange feels that the question is inappropriate. The reason why there are reputation points is to let others know what or how well you ask or answer questions. Also this question should be on the islam site.