# My answer has been deleted and I've edited it

Tags: discussion, specific-post, undelete-request

I'm referring to the question [Are there any schools of thought which consider the science of Fiqh to be Bidah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/are-there-any-schools-of-thought-which-consider-the-science-of-fiqh-to-be-bidah)

My answer now is as follows:

> As i haven't heared of such a school and as there's no reason why one
>   should pretend that fiqh is bid'ah i'll try to proof that this can't
>   be the case as it is quoted in both the Quran and the Sunnah here just
>   some examples:
>
> - Surat an-Nisa' [(4:78)](http://quran.com/4/78) fiqh as understanding and believing once they do
> - Surat at-Tawba [(9:122)](http://quran.com/9/122) fiqh as a fard kifaya
> - Surat at-Tawba [(9:127)](http://quran.com/9/127) addressing the Munafiqiyn who don't understand (fiqh= understanding)
> - Surat Taha [(20:28)](http://quran.com/20/28) fiqh as understanding (the speech of Musa (peace be upon him))
> - Mu’awiyah (RAA) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “When Allah wishes good for anyone, He bestows upon him the Fiqh
>     (comprehension) of the religion.” Agreed upon. [Sahih al-Bukhari &
>     Muslim etc.]
> - [Difference](http://sunnah.com/urn/1302410) between one who just narrated and one who understood a speech
>
> As you may see the word fiqh was known and applied as the Messenger of
>   Allah (peace be upon him) used to do fatwa himself. So rejecting this
>   or considering it a bid'ah would be rejecting something our Messenger
>   used to do and asked as to do!
>
> So the Answer to your Question should be NO!
>
> Now if you mean by this to specify chapters etc in book of fiqh. One
>   may speak about a good bid'ah بدعة حسنة in this case i think you will
>   find many who will call it so, see for example this [fatwa in
>   Arabic](http://islamqa.info/ar/183220)!
>
> and Allah knows best!

I think now the reason for deleting is lifted.

Comment: Well somebody found a good answer for that question as far as i can say, so for me the discussion could be closed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line I believe really sums up the bulk of the problems I have with your entire post (emphasis mine):

> So the Answer to your Question **should be** NO!

We are not a site for telling people what they "should be" following when it comes to Islam. As Caleb so well-put it [some time ago](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/islam-stack-exchange-is-not-for-debates-or-apologetics#comment4505_1255) (emphasis again mine):

> **Content here should be descriptive of the way things are** (including if they are debated) not prescriptive of the way they should be (and thus dragging the debate into this arena)

Your arguments are well-articulated, but the answer they're supporting is for *exactly the wrong question*; they have nothing whatsoever to do with whether any schools *do* believe that the science of fiqh is or is not bid'ah, it's just arguing why people *shouldn't* believe that the science of fiqh is bid'ah. In other words, the *vast* majority of your post is being *prescriptive* rather than *descriptive*.

Take that out, and the only *relevant* parts of your post that would remain would be as follows:

> I haven't heard of such a school and there's no reason why one should [believe] that fiqh is bid'ah. So the answer to your question should be NO!

Which is severely lacking the meat required for an actual *answer*.

Comment: But if i just said: NO i couldn't find any and as fiqh was known and applied in the early days of islam calling it bida'h would mean to reject some part of the islamic teaching. I would get comments about a lack of sources etc.

Comment: @MediSaif Yes. But adding in the *wrong* references doesn't help that; like I said, you spend most of the post answering *exactly the wrong question*.

Comment: The expression "the answer should be no" was a bit inaccurate what i ment is according to my search the answer as it seems should be no! I never want or wanted to say what one should do or not! I'll then try to find an appropriate answer and 5thanks for making it clear to me :)

Comment: @medi saif: 'the answer should be No!', could be taken as rhetorical strategy - ie emphasis; but it's liable to be misconstrued too.