# Can we open 73 sect question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, re-open

The question https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24755/the-hadith-foretelling-that-islam-will-split-into-73-sects is very legitimate and has abackground. How can we know which one of 73 sects is is right when we know the rest of them will go to hell?

I think this answer is closed because the mods fear the answer might incline towards shia faith and hence it should be closed. I do not think that is the case. We should allow such question and by allowing it we learn how to respect each other faith and learn about each other. There is no need to close is. The question is very legitimate. Can we learn some tolerance from such question? The questioner clearly did not side with any particular faith and is neutral question.

Answer (score 2):

How is that question anything *but* opinion-based? As I explained in my comment when I closed it:

> Obviously, every sect has their own evidences to support why *their* sect is the right one; this question is just going to attract argument and opinion, which is not what this site is for. See relevant meta discussion here: [Islam—Stack Exchange is not for debates or apologetics](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22)

That question was closed *after* it had already attracted exactly the sorts of argument and opinion [we don't allow here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22), and had already required moderator intervention. And I see absolutely no reason to believe that undeleting and re-opening it wouldn't result in exactly the same situation: The site is still not designed for these sorts of questions, the community is still unable/unwilling to handle these sorts of questions, and moderators would still be required to intervene yet again.

Your post…it does absolutely nothing to address any of the *actual* problems with the post. Instead, you accuse moderators of being biased because the answers *might* incline towards opinions that the moderators disagree with, but that's pretty much ignoring the *real* problem: As stated, the problem was that the answers would incline towards opinions *at all*. Whether I, you, or others personally agree or disagree with them is irrelevant; they would still be *opinions*, not *answers*.

The Stack Exchange model is not geared towards that sort of question. It never has been, and unless you can can present a stronger argument than "Can we learn some tolerance" it's unlikely that that will change: [Real questions have *answers*, **not *items* or *ideas* or *opinions***.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: First this is s very valid question. Second the questioner gave background of deobandi and barailwi. These two sects are generally peace loving  with no violence. I am sure they can handle this question very well. You yourself dragged sectarianism into it to by deleting one answer and quoting "this is shia propaganda..." so infact your way of looking at it is wrong. Let it sit there, I do not see any arguments in the answers that you have referred to in the answer.

Comment: @muslim1 This question is the epitome of a [Truth question](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1442/2469). Those questions simply cannot be addressed here.