# Is being an atheist; crime in this community just like Islamic countries

Tags: discussion

The question speaks for itself.

Islamic countries bring shame to world by executing people who do not believe in God.

Being an atheist, I do not want this website to exist on internet under an awesome platform i.e. Stack Exchange.

Why do you believe in a 1382 year old book and not science?

Why does this community even exist?

For preachment purposes? That's all I can figure out.

Comment: See the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for what topics islam.se is for. It's not an apologetics website, although those do sift in a lot now and then. It's in everyone's interest to have solid information on Islam, us atheists as much as anyone else.

Answer (score 5):

We form a significant proportion of the human race (1/4th) and people, both Muslims and others are interested in having reliable, sourced and well-presented information about our religion, and so this community exists, just like [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) and [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/).

If you don't want this site to exist, then you are welcome to not use it.

Answer (score 5):

I'll skip the rant, and answer the Islam.SE-related questions:

> Why does this community even exist ?

Take a look around; we're here to learn about Islam.  As long as you [play nice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) with others, it's fine to be an atheist here; you don't even have to like Islam to participate.

I personally don't like homeopathy, yet the journal [*Homeopathy*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/14754916?sdc=1) gets published by Elsevier, who also publish journals containing some of my best papers.  I guess *I don't like something* is not reason enough for it not to exist.

> For preachment purposes ? That's all I can figure out.

Preaching is not the intention of the site.  (See e.g.: [Islam—Stack Exchange is not for debates or apologetics](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/17163).)  That being said, (a) studying Islam will likely cause people to develop a more (dis)favorable opinion, and (b) preaching seems to slip in from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

What ever you are doesn't play a roll.

On this site we are discussing Islam related topics, on an academical level, if you have a question on that you are welcome if not than spamming the site with views that are off-topic, and not going ahead with the site policies of [being nice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) then you neither are welcome on Islam SE nor would you be on any site in the stack exchange network!