# Why there is so many negativity in this community?

Tags: discussion, sunnah

I'am so sorry to say this, but each time i answered based on what i believe to be true, solid reasoning behind it and a couple of research, there are people who disagree, downvote, and trying to argue? What is this place?
I said Quora is better community then.

If you ask question, answer will come from any point of view, many perspective will be pointed towards your question. If you dislike the answer please just swallow it, don't delete or downvote it. Respect the effort and time of the people who willing to give an answer.

Why is that? why us muslim have this kind of mentality? If you wanted to argue just comment and have deductive argument. Getting rid of people you think are wrong, doesn't mean you're right.

Comment: @UmH look at the Home section there are so many question yet so few answer. Most of the answer whether minus score, not accepted or deleted. Don't be offended brother, i look at the truth. Cheers

Comment: Please read this if you haven't: [Islam—Stack Exchange is not for debates or apologetics](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255)

Answer (score 7):

> If you ask question, answer will come from any point of view, many perspective will be pointed towards your question. If you dislike the answer please just swallow it, don't delete or downvote it.

Maybe you've forgotten the entire point of this site? People ask questions to get answers; if they ask a question and get answers from a perspective that they didn't want, someone is either asking or answering the wrong question. If you don't know what perspective a question is looking for, don't just assume they want yours: Either ask them to clarify what they want, or provide a comprehensive answer that covers the spectrum.

You want us to respect the time and effort you put into your answer, but you also need to respect the time and effort of the questioner and of all future visitors who read that question only to not find the answer they're looking for, as well as the time and effort of all the volunteers who curate the site to make sure those questioners can *find* their answers.

Telling people to "just swallow" answers they don't want doesn't really help anyone, all it does is open the door for people to push their opinions on others whether they like it or not, a door we as a site have long since decided we don't want open here. If we want people to ask interesting questions here, they kinda *need* to feel like they're actually getting something out of it. Something like, for example, an actual answer they're looking for.

And if you want to argue in comments, there are plenty of sites out there that let you do that: Again, we are not one of them. People here ask questions to get *answers*, not for opinions, guesswork and arguments.

Comment: This way of thinking seems to be bias. I had a similar situation in the Christian SE, were a Christian wanted to know if the trinity was true/not. I disproved it on the basis of scripture, research, logic and mathematics i.e. not guesswork/opinions/arguments. But it was deleted as it was damaging to their false teaching that they follow. The moderator said similar to you said, that we want a Christian point of view, but I said questioner whats to sincerely know the truth. So what do you want the correct ansewer or one that based on a peoples opinion/belief

Comment: @AsanRamzan When dealing with religion, everyone believes that what they believe is "the truth", and letting each answer provide it's own different "the truth" is likely to just confuse the questioner more than actually help him, which is kinda exactly the opposite of what we're trying to do here. Scope is important.

Answer (score -1):

One piece of advice that someone gave me early on for this site:

> "We should not answer questions for rep. We should answer questions for the sake of Allah."

This should apply whether it's answering questions or voting on answers. Islam is complex, sometimes blurred with culture rather than the truth itself. What someone grew up with may not necessarily be true. And sometimes what you answer also may not coincide with what someone grew up with. Remember that we're a global community, with people coming from many different schools.

You'll have to put a little effort into convincing them, which is why we're very evidence based. Nobody can argue with a clear verse from the Qur'an or Hadith, only the interpretation of it. If you give a sincere interpretation, it should be fine. Opinions from scholars and fatwas are much more debatable, as they could be politically biased, but often there's a lot of research put into them.

Jazakallahu Khairan.